# Very Odd DNS Reset Issue

Tags: networking, wireless, dns, cache

Running Ubuntu 16.04 on an HP laptop. I have a very strange issue that is driving me nuts. When I'm connected to a very intermittent wifi access point sometimes I will get disconnected. When that happens even after reconnecting to the access point the network is useless. Chrome gives me the following error message:

This site can’t be reached

www.google.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
Try:
Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

I have tried searching the forums and have tried the following commands to no avail.

sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload

sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In a standard Ubuntu desktop install, DNS is managed by a DNSMasq instance started by Network Manager. I've certainly witnessed NM crash a few times when coming back from suspend and exhibit things like you describe.

I fix them by running:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Depending on how often you're doing this, it might be worth digging in and working out why it's crashing, or which bit of the puzzle crashes, but usually running that once a week is just easier ☹

Comment: Thanks, I'll give these suggestions a try the next time it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have fallen foul of resolvconf , its a package that networkmanager uses to switch DNS servers to fit multiple connections.

heres the online manpage
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/resolvconf.8.html

first list the interfaces its aware of

```
resolvconf -i
```

then the files it manages

```
resolvconf -l
```

then delete the old interfaces

```
resolvconf -d interface
```